# Storing a dynamic variable in json data?

Tags: php, json

Is it possible to pass variable data into variable stored in json?

Here I have 2 set variables.
Then I get the json stored in the database:

```
$example1 = "data example one";
$example2 = "data example two";

$template = JsonTemplate::find(1);
$data = unserialize($template->json);
```

The stored json has a variables that I want to pass $example1 and $example2

```
          [
            $example1 => [
                1 => [
                    0 => 1,
                    1 => 2,
                ],
            ],
            $example2 => [
                1 => [
                    0 => 1,
                    1 => 3,
                ],
            ],
```

Then return `$data`

```
return $data;
```

New returned json would be:

```
          [
            data example one => [
                1 => [
                    0 => 1,
                    1 => 2,
                ],
            ],
            data example two => [
                1 => [
                    0 => 1,
                    1 => 3,
                ],
            ],
```

Comment: use json_encode after creating php array. json_encode($data)

Comment: json_encode($data) returns json but does not update the variable. the variable stays a variable... "{"$example1":{"1":[1,2]}"

Comment: So your saved template literally has `$example1` in it? What's this `JsonTemplate` class you're using? Does it include anything for replacing variables? If not, probably a simple [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) will do the trick for you.

Comment: trying str_replace like this `$newdata = str_replace('$example1',"new example",$data);` and $example1 is not updated at all. Then I tried `$newdata = str_replace('$example1','new example',$data['$example1']);` and $example1 was removed and not replaced with anything.

Comment: I figured out I have to encode the data first before I str_replace. It worked after that.